# Command Parameter "Position" for MouseDown event

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a `ResourceDictionary` with `Canvas` and I need to get position of `mouseDown` event (and a color of this WPFpixel).

So, I have a XAML code like this:

```
<Canvas  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="200" Height="200" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="{StaticResource CustomBrush}">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                        <local:EventToCommand RouteEventArgs="True" Command="local:ColorPicker.SomeAction" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Position}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

So, in my .cs file I can get position from command parameter like `e.Parameter`.
I tried to find any info, but all examples were with `MouseEventArgs` except `ExecutedRoutedEventArgs`. So, the question is: which `CommandParameter` I need to use? or may be you suggest any other sulution solve it.

And my second question is how to get the color. I have a custom filling with a gradient and I can't analyze what the exact color has exact pixel.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have a found a solution.
I added a handler 
`AddHandler(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Get_position), true);`
then I  get the coordinates in function `Get_position`

```
    private static void Get_position(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyObject parent = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
        while (parent != null && !(parent is Canvas))
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);

        if (parent != null)
        {
            var point = e.GetPosition(parent as UIElement);
            int x = (int)point.X;
            int y = (int)point.Y;
        }
    }
```

Then I can send them to my control. Perhaps, it's not the best solution, but it works...

About calculating the color of pixel, I didn't find any solution. However, I solve it by calculating R,G,B values. I have a Canvas with gradient brush. So, if I know the width/height I can calculate them.
On the other hand it's still interesting question for me.